# Blitting an image according to countdown

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game using Python 3.5.1/Pygame, and I need to animate a drop that falls from the ceiling. This is my original code:

```
def dropping(X,startY,endY,speed):
    if drip == True:
        for index in range(startY,endY,speed):
            screen.blit(drop,(X,index))

while insert_variable_here == True:
    dropping(X,startY,endY,speed)
    pygame.display.update()
```

This code blits all of it at once instead of waiting for the next loop of "insert_variable_here". How can I fix this?

Comment: For starters, don't define a function in a loop.

Comment: @Gerrat Ah thank you. Didn't mean to type it that way. I've edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try storing the countdown as a string then using if statements to determine which image to blit.

(I haven't used Pygame is months and have forgotten how to blit, but you will get the idea)

```
import time
import pygame
*code here*
countdown = str(your countdown code)
if countdown > 60:
    blit the image
```